# Split a database field with coldfusion

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

We are performing a data import from a table into another table in a different DB
i.e.: I have a field in SQL server table "A" as  name : this, that (Test) 
which needs to be compared with a  a table "B as "Firstname and lastname field which is stored separately
so when ever the name on the table A i.e. "this" matches to  this in the table B Firstname field i want to store the value and if not i just store "not here only there"

```
<cfquery name="qryCCtoTableB" datasource="#sDataSource#">
SELECT         SUBSTRING(Name, comma + 1, paren-comma-1) as FirstName 
               ,SUBSTRING(Name, 1, comma - 1) as LastName from CC
cross apply (
     SELECT CHARINDEX( ',', Name + ',' ) as comma) a(comma)
cross apply (
      SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX( '(', Name + 
                   '(', comma+1),0),comma+1) as paren) b(paren)
```

and i am comparing this to

```
<cfquery name="qryCCtoTableB" datasource="#sDataSource#">
            SELECT  ID
            FROM    TableB
            WHERE       TableB.FirstName = '#qryCCtoTableB.FirstName#'
                 and 
                    TableB.LastName = '#qryCCtoTableB.OwnerLastName#'
</cfquery>
```

and i want to store it to

```
<cfset sName = '#qryCCtoTableB.ID#'>
```

however when i do this i donot get a result *

for *sName but whenever i do the qryCCtoTableB with an OR i get the
 result but i have to compare first and last name*

  *

what could i be doing  wrong?

Comment: 1) From what you have described this is really a SQL question, not CF. So it is important your tags indicate your DBMS *and* version. 2) Your choice of column names is a little confusing ("this", "that", ...), but if I understand correctly there are three columns involved:  `tableA.FullName, tableB.FirstName, tableB.LastName` .. correct?  As an aside, if you must do this - keep in mind splitting proper names is notoriously error-prone.

Comment: If you are comparing names, you probably have the wrong approach.  Is there any reason why you can't import into a staging table with a couple blank fields for first and last name, and then update those based on the full name?

Comment: @Leigh, I thought "this, that" was a sample of a full name.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Yeah, you could be right .. but not the greatest choice for an example - way too ambiguous. Something immediately obvious "Smith, John" or "Doe, Jane" is *much* clearer.

Comment: *i do not get a result* Well that means the values you extracted in the first query, do not match any of the records in tableB. You need to dump the actual values so you can figure out why. Also, why use CF for this? Why not a JOIN, temp table, etcetera...?

Comment: well the names are there on both the table but for some reason it doesnot match, i will check into temptable i dont know what etcetera means??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera

Comment: Look into using a simple JOIN first. *RE: but for some reason it doesnot match* That is why you need to dump the actual first/last name values calculated in your query. Obviously some of them are **not** what you think they should be.. You need to visually review the calculated values to find out why they do not match the records in your other table.